# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error in my browser

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm trying to run this AngularJS that should modify the URL without reloading the page but the console says Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Where is the problem?

```js
var app = angular.module("SearchAPP", ['ng-route']);

app.run(['$route', '$rootScope', '$location',
  function($route, $rootScope, $location) {
    var original = $location.path;
    $location.path = function(path, reload) {
      if (reload === false) {
        var lastRoute = $route.current;
        var un = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
          $route.current = lastRoute;
          un();
        });
      }
      return original.apply($location, [path]);
    };
  }
]);

app.controller('GetController', ['$http', '$scope', '$location',
  function($http, $scope, $rootScope, $location) {

    $scope.click = function() {

      var response = $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:4567/search',
        method: "GET",
        params: {
          keyword: $scope.searchKeyword
        }
      });

      response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.searchResults1 = data;
        // $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $location.path('/' + $scope.searchKeyword, false);
      });

      response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Error.");
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach `angualar-route.js` and use `ngRoute` instead of `ng-route`

```
var app = angular.module("SearchAPP", ['ngRoute']);
```